# show same id one time but in column count how many times php

Tags: php, mysql

I am displaying data from database, but I want to display one time same id but in other column how many times its stored in MySQL database.
Thanks!

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['completed_consu_id'])) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM completed_consumers";
} else {
$query = "SELECT * FROM completed_consumers WHERE consu_id=consu_id";
}
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
$numberofrow=mysql_num_rows($result);

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$consu_id = $row['consu_id'];
$consu_first_name = $row['consu_first_name'];
$consu_last_name = $row['consu_last_name'];
$consu_phone = $row['consu_phone'];
$consu_email = $row['consu_email'];
$consu_address = $row['consu_address'];
$consu_city = $row['consu_city'];
$consu_state = $row['consu_state'];
$consu_zip = $row['consu_zip'];
$consu_IP = $row['consu_IP'];
$status = $row['status'];

$query2 ="SELECT consu_id, COUNT(*) FROM completed_consumers WHERE consu_id=$consu_id GROUP BY consu_id";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
$numberofrow2=mysql_num_rows($result2);
$times= $numberofrow2;
echo $times;
```

This is code i have written, Its displaying all the consumers details and how many they have entered data or details, but I want to show one time consumer details/Name but how many time they submitted data in "times" column.

Like David consumer added 2 times, Monika added 1 time, Arshi added 3 times data/details, but when i retrieve data its showing 6 rows in table, i want to show in 3 row, 1 for David, 1 for Monika, 1 for Arshi but with how many times they added in "times" column when i retrieve it details.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? It's difficult to tell what you mean exactly.

Comment: Its showing howmany times, but also show same numbers of time in row when i display, i want to show one time same id but with numbers of times stored in database.

Comment: I am storing persons with few coupon points, and same person can add many time coupons points, and i want to display same person display one time when i retrieve but how many times he added coupons, like David added 2 times added 2 coupons and Monika added one time, so result or when i retrieve from database, it must show both name just one time but in other columns how many times they added coupon

Comment: @Arvind updates to your question for clarification should be in the body of the question, not the comments. Please edit your question and put these details there.

Comment: I see. Can you edit your question to show the relevant schema? A create statement would be ideal. (Also, what @jdv said. ^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause.

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM completed_consumers WHERE consu_id=$consu_id GROUP BY consu_id
```